# Is there ever a response to the, "check for solution and close" dialog in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Usually iTunes crashes for me in Vista x64 half the time it starts. I have tried troubleshooting, reading all sorts of things and attempting many of them. The only way I can get rid of it is to kill it with Task Manager, and the question is always asked "check for a solution and close" or something else I no longer pay attention to.

Has a reply EVER gotten back to this dialog in Windows? I don't mean specifically to the iTunes issue, but to any application freeze. It seems like a total waste of time dialog to me. Why bother me, if it never does anything?

Comment: Thanks to all. I agree it is always worth sending, in the off chance that it will help.  Sometimes in windows server 2003 I have gotten a reply, but not Vista or Win7 thus far

Comment: I think it may have to do with how well your system generally runs and how clean it is. You are less likely to get common errors.

Answer (score 4):

I have actually gotten a response in one or two of those dialogs.  Generally, it has always been to update to the latest version of the software, because there was a known issue with the version that I was using with the version of Windows that I was on at the time.

Comment: How did you get the response? Email? Dialog box? Windows update?

Comment: After it sent the error report a link came up in the dialog that said something to the tune of "View a possible solution to this problem"

Answer (score 2):

I think Microsoft usually forward on the reports to the makers of the software, so they can come up with a fix.

I have got solutions offered to me several times in the past, and sometimes they have worked, and managed to dig up obscure device drivers that I couldn't find using Google, for example. They don't always appear automatically though, sometimes you have to go to the Action Center and manually check for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I am with you: No, I have never gotten it to return a solution either, but sometimes the data in the "View problem details" has been helpful to me.

If you do send the information to Microsoft, while it may or may not help, I think they do look at some of the responses (maybe automated) to help improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

Several times, I already got back some solution. Usually a web page will open up afterwards and there you will find some more information. (Sometimes there is a how-to on how to solve the problem. Other times there is a message that they are in contact with the producer of the software, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does something, but since you are not the only user of the Microsoft Windows operating system, you might not get a solution to all of your specific problems. IMNSHO, you should always send bug reports to Microsoft. The only thing that can happen -- and, probably, in many cases, *will happen* -- is that bugs and other issues are fixed. Indeed, we all know that Windows 7 is better than Vista, and perhaps Microsoft used the collected information to achieve some parts of this improvement. (For instance, they might observe what kinds of things that cause the most trouble, etc.)